# What happens if a follower meets themselves?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've started a run on Nightmare with my Witch Doctor, and I noticed that although I've started with all of my followers and artisans from the beginning, I still have quests that involve me meeting them for the first time.

In the Blacksmith's case, he just disappeared from his workshop and I had to go meet him elsewhere in town.  However, my Templar didn't disappear when I met him for the first time in the Cathedral.  At the time, I had the Enchantress with me, and they shared a few unique lines of dialog.

What happens if I take a follower to meet themselves?  Do they sit the mission out and are replaced by their pre-follower selves?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I frequently have [Tyrael meet himself](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151266825) at the Pinnacle of Heaven. They both take it far to easily...

Comment: I'm reminded of a movie with a title that I can't remember at the moment, where people could be in alternate dimensions and meet themselves, and if they touched each other they both ceased to excist.

Comment: [Don't cross the streams... it would be Very Bad...](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverTheSelvesShallMeet)

Comment: Double Templar? What does it meeeeeeeeeean?

Comment: I wonder if this still happens because we can now finish each quests once

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned, they follow you for a time as they did the first time, and only after where it would have asked "Do you want X to join your party" the second disappears.  The brief bits of bonus dialogue are as follows:

### Double Templar

After releasing and talking with the "Warrior"

> **Templar:** Why have you come here, brother?
> **Warrior:** One of our number has forsaken his vows and joined the demonic coven that infests this fallen cathedral.
> **Templar:** Damn that traitor!  We will make him pay.

After re-arming

> **Templar:** Evil cowers at the sight of just one templar.  Two will bring it to its knees.

After killing Jondar he simply waits at the top of the steps then disappears.

### Double Scoundrel

After meeting the clone:

> **Scoundrel (1):** Wait, aren't you from the guild?  How could I forget a handsome devil like you!
> **Scoundrel (2):** Why, yes, of course!  It's good to see you again!

He simply leaves when you start his quest at the waypoint.

### Double Enchantress

After getting the first quest from her:

> **[Your] Enchantress:** She seems very familiar...

At the roadblock:

> **Enchantress:** You must be one of my sisters!  How wonderful it is to see you again.

After the bridge she simply leaves.

Answer (score 8):

You actually get both of them for a while, during the time where the follower isn't officially under your control.  At the point that the follower would normally join your party officially, the second one disappears and you're back to just your normal follower.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing *really* happens (outside some short dialogue) and it is pretty bizarre.

You still have to play out the quests as if you have not done them before, even if the followers meet. They don't have any interactions in town either.

For example: I took the enchantress back to town before she opens the bridge, and walked her right up to the other enchantress and there was no reaction.

Comment: I had the Scoundrel in Nightmare when I reached the part where you encounter the Scoundrel.  When we met up, the two had a specific dialog (something along the lines of "hey, I know you!") that was pretty amusing.  So "nothing happens" is actually wrong.

Comment: @Beofett - I should have put the qualifier "nothing REALLY happens" aside from some short dialogue. You still play out the scenes as if the follower never existed.

Comment: -1: this is really just griping about Blizzard not doing it the way you wanted them to, and it took me a second to realize that your alternative scenarios aren't actually in the game.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize my opinion after stating the answer would raise so many pitchforks.