# List of Follower conversations with each other (not achievement)

Tags: diablo-iii

> ***Note***: I am **not** referring to the follower conversations that you
>   select using 'Talk' for the 3 achievements.

Is there a complete list of the various interactions the followers have with each other when they're in town, as well as when they meet their duplicates in Nightmare mode (assuming you took along the right follower). I found some of their banter quite interesting, but I don't want to just hang around in the sidekicks' corner to hear more of it.

Also, are there any new convos if all 3 are left together? From what I've observed, it is just any 2 talking back & forth.

Comment: The part about meeting themselves is covered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69997/13845

Comment: Yes, I'd read that earlier before posting this question - but if someone is kind (& crazy!) enough to enumerate all of their idle gossip, it may be better to include the duplicate convos here as well.

Comment: I've listened to some of these.  They're amusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the author of http://www.d3lexicon.com/, a complete list of all conversations is given [here](http://www.d3lexicon.com/conversation#all). The data is gathered from the internals of the Diablo III client.

You can filter the conversations by "Fol" for "Follower" at the beginning, then by "En" for "Enchantress", "Sc" for "Scoundrel", "Tp" for "Templar", and "All" for all of them.

Example "[Fol Sc En Wrld 2](http://www.d3lexicon.com/conversation/fol-sc-en-wrld-2)" (talk between scoundrel and enchantress):

> **Scoundrel:** However did you become so good at charming others?
>   **Enchantress:** I learned the charm spell long ago and spent many hours practicing it.
>   **Scoundrel:** That's not what I—never mind.

Example "[Fol All Camp 02](http://www.d3lexicon.com/conversation/fol-all-camp-02)" (talk between all three followers):

> **Scoundrel:** Kormac, anyone can tell that you are lonely. Let me help you find a woman.
>   **Templar:** I already told you: I have forsaken the pleasures of the flesh! How hard can that be for you to understand?
>   **Scoundrel:** There's no sin in merely talking to a lady, is there?
>   **Enchantress:** The way you talk, there is.

Example "[Fol Player En Wrld 004](http://www.d3lexicon.com/conversation/fol-player-en-wrld-004)" (talk between enchantress and player):

> **Enchantress:** The templar is so strange around me at times.
>   **Player:** He's in love with you.
>   **Enchantress**: What?!
>   **Player:** You never noticed?
>   **Enchantress:** No!